# What is the maximum number of private keys you can use via SSH Agent (Pageant)

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, ssh-agent

While answering [Re-using SSH keys](https://serverfault.com/questions/819533/re-using-ssh-keys/819777#819777) I had a question of my own, **is there a limit to the number of ssh keys you can hold in ssh agents?** (and/or putty pageant).

(as a test, I loaded 10 keys into my pageant and didn't seem to have an issue)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At last for the `ssh-agent`, the only limit is about the maximum memory available for the user or process. [The keys are stored](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/ssh-agent.c#L664) in the [linked list](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/00df97ff68a49a756d4b977cd02283690f5dfa34/openbsd-compat/sys-queue.h#L477) which does not have any effective limit and all the constructs. The only counter used is [`int nentries;`](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/ssh-agent.c#L122), which limits the effective amount of keys to [2 147 483 647](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/limits_h.htm), which is quite enough.

The limit is more in the practical usability. Once you load a lot of keys into the agent, they are send sequentially to the server (unless otherwise specially configured), which rejects after 3 or 6 public key tests (prevents the key enumeration for user). For some people, this can be also considered as a privacy issue, since the keys can be paired with, for example your github accounts.